# Responsive DIV's. Posts on my site don't line up

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've been battling this for weeks and I just can't figure out what is wrong. I have 3 columns with 2 rows. So a total of 6 posts in on section. When the amount of text in the title of one post is a Line longer than the rest of the posts, it seems to throw the whole grid outta wack.

Below is the code for the 6 boxes

```
        <div class="row block02">
                                <? **sql stuff**
                                ?>
        <div class="col-1-3">
            <div class="wrap-col">

                <a href="blog.php?post_id=<? echo($result_miniblog['post_id']); ?>"><img src="../images/<? echo($result_miniblog['image']); ?>" alt="<? echo($result_miniblog['image_alt']); ?>" /></a>
            <h2>    
                <a class="tag" style="color:#2980b9;" href="#"><? echo($result_miniblog['post_category']); ?></a>
                <a class="headline" href="blog.php?post_id=<? echo($result_miniblog['post_id']); ?>"><? echo($result_miniblog['post_title']); ?></a>
                <a class="byline" href="blah">
                <br />John Doe</a>
            </h2>
            </div>
        </div>

                                <?}?>

    </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the above code

```
.block02 {min-height:250px;}
.block02 {margin:20px 10px; text-align:left;}
.block02 p{font-size:16px;}
.block02 img {margin: 0 1em .5em 0; min-width: 100%;height:auto;padding: 0 0 0 0;border:4px solid black;background-size:cover;background-position:center;}

.row{}
.row:before,.row:after { content: '\0020'; display: block; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; }
.row:after{clear: both; }
.row{zoom: 1;}

.col-1-3{width:33.33%;}

.byline {font-family:raleway;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;color:silver;}
.byline .logo {color:black;}
.byline .author {color:#999;}
.byline a {text-decoration:none;color:#999}
a.byline {color:#888;font-size:14px;}
a.tag {color:#16a085;font-size:13px;display:block;margin-bottom:.25em;text-transform:uppercase;margin-top:.25em;}
a.headline {color:#000;margin-bottom:.5em;font-size:18px;}

.wrap-col{margin:10px;}
```

[DIV's not lining up even when images are same size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVd5h.jpg)

Comment: Is there any way you can incorporate a clearfix after every third post?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that. I'm pretty new to all this coding stuff ;)

Comment: Do you have a link to page or can post the code in JSFiddle ?

Comment: add a clearfix after each item.

.clearfix{
     clear:both;
}

Alternately, use flexbox in a single 1 col row to manage the layout. It will handle alignment discrepancies like a champ.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. thanks

Comment: sorry, 12 col row, not 1 col row. Ran out of time to edit the response.

Comment: Korgue - Where should I add the clearfix exactly? can I add clear:both; to col-1-3?

Comment: @Korgrue The clearfix just lined everything up in 1 column instead of the 2 rows of 3

Comment: Hmm, then I would recommend saving yourself a bunch of hassle and just use flexbox. 5 lines of css will layout your entire grid.

Comment: Any ideas how I can put a clearfix on every 3rd post when I'm using a database to populate the page? is there some sort of (elseif) statement I could use?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.col {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-1">
    row 1 column 1
   </div>
   <div class="col col-2">
    row 1 column 2  
   </div>
   <div class="col col-3">
    row 1 column 3
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-1">
    row 1 column 1
   </div>
   <div class="col col-2">
    row 1 column 2  
   </div>
   <div class="col col-3">
    row 1 column 3
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing is that your col-1-3 is not floated.  Change that css to

```
.col-1-3 { width:33.33%; float:left; min-height:200px; }
```

Comment: I changed it and the posts are still screwy. I'm really mind boggled right now! lol

Comment: its weird because the posts line up if the title lengths are all the same, but as soon as they are different, they start to offset..

Comment: yup, they will be odd if the heights are not the same.  that's how it works.  so you need to set a minumum height or truncate the length of the title to make sure its overflow is hidden, perhaps.

Comment: I'll try setting the height now.

Comment: add the min-height that i put in the edit of my solution - adjust if not tall enough to allow a longer title.

Comment: like
`.col-1-3 { width:33.33%; float:left; min-height:250px; Overflow:hidden; }`
?

Comment: sorry to have been so random in what i was saying...you need to set your min-height high enough so that any issue with overflowing titles is overcome and the total height of the rows is identical.  the overflow idea was something else.  to see if you qualify for that...let me ask, do you wish for titles that are too long to be shortened to fit on one line?

Comment: one other question - why not use twitter bootstrap rather than roll your own responsive?  it's terribly easy to use and the documentation is excellent. http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/getting-started/

Comment: to be honest, I just really started dabbling in this stuff, so I haven't really looked into it. But I will be! I did set a good height and that seemed to fix my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: thank you for making these both as the solution - like a double whammy here, eh?

Comment: sorry to bring this back up, but I just noticed that nothing has changed in the Chrome browser.. These fixes appear to have only worked in windows. Can I send you the url address? if you wouldn't mind looking at it

Comment: sure i'll look at it

Comment: for some reason when I open it in chrome its all out of wack